# 16 amp 240V compressor on 30A breaker

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

I’m running a 16A 240V air compressor with 3HP on a 30A rated breaker. Is this safe or should I use a 20 A breaker instead?

[image: motor info]

Comment: What size are the wires for the motor branch circuit?

Comment: @JimStewart -- this is an air compressor, not an air conditioner :P

Answer (score 4):

You're operating under the *motor rules* here, NEC article 430.

430.22 for the wire size, 125% of amp rating, so 16A x 125% = 20A wire... but due to the horsepower rating of the motor and 430.6(A)(1), you're a little over, and need 25A wire.

#12 NM and UF cable cannot be used at 25A. 240.4(D) isn't the problem; it's 334.80 which limits NM to the 60C thermal rating.  (#12=20A).

430.52 for the breaker size. Breaker is allowed to be up to 225% of the motor rating, unless the motor label says otherwise.

Comment: Note that the 430 rules require the table full-load amps to be used (this is 430.6(A)(1)), which means that 20A wire ampacity isn't *quite* sufficient for the OP's motor (3HP @ 230VAC = 17A, not the 16A given on the motor nameplate)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel If other than 60°C ratted UF or TW wouldn't #12 be sufficient for 25A since section 430 is listed in 240.4(G)?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease -- yeah, although I suspect that #12 NM would also be insufficient due to the precise wording of the 334.80 text governing its ampacity

Comment: The wire used is a 10Ga wire that’s run about 4 ft from the box. The. picks up with whatever the wire is for the motor cord and I’m not sure if that’s 10 ga.

Comment: @JosephAndaverde -- yeah, you're fine then

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added that.  Well, that's disturbing. Why would UL approve it with 16A nameplate? 16A is a magic number.  Yes, 334.80 should bind NM even if 240.4 allows you to go higher.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- because the nameplate amp rating is what's used to set motor overloads

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of the wiring up to the compressor is able to carry a 30A rating, then the question is whether the wiring in the air compressor itself is capable of handling 30A.  The motor is thermally protected (says so on the label) which will limit the current in the case of a long-term overload that would melt the insulation and cause a short.  The 30A breaker will magnetically trip if you have a short inside of the motor and it will be fast enough to not risk melting the insulation.

So, I suspect because of the thermal overload built into the motor that your setup is safe.

However, if it were my place, I would still swap out the 30A breaker for the NEC 125% rule of the running current which would be 16A * 1.25 = 20A since I always like knowing if something is operating out of spec and I would rather have a nuisance trip than burning some wires on the compressor.

Note that the 125% rule officially only applies to continuous loads for circuits that run for 3 hours or longer.

Comment: But compressor motors can take a large surge current on start-up.  A lower current breaker may also have to be a slower one.

Comment: @SimonB - that's correct, however the standard breaker is a C-curve and the magnetic trip is around 7x the rated current.  The thermal trip can handle over 2x the current for about 10 seconds and 5x the current for about 1 second.  Normally that is fine to handle start-up currents and compressors typically have about a 1-second startup time.  Slower starting motors connected to heavy equipment require D-curve breakers.